# If case for publist biblatex options (for .cls file)

Tags: biblatex, conditionals, documentclass-writing, biblatex-publist

I have this if case I run for deciding some options for `publist`. I tried to use the `\ExecutePublistOptions{ }` to change the publist options, but it seems this doesn't work in the .cls file/ preamble. I *could* import `biblatex` differently for every document class option, but this seems ineficcient as most of the options are the same.

**I would like to modify `publist` options without importing `biblatex` *every* time**. Is this possible? (the solution must work in preamble/ .cls file)

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{soft}{rgb}{0.45,0.45,0.45}
\newcommand{\softbullet}{\textcolor{soft}{\small\textbullet}\hspace{0.5em}}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@displayvon
%\DeclareOption{vonname=true}{\@displayvontrue}

\newif\if@publistnormal
%\DeclareOption{bib=normal}{\@publistnormaltrue}

\newif\if@publisthighlight
%\DeclareOption{bib=highlightname}{\@publisthighlighttrue}

\newif\if@publisthideonly
%\DeclareOption{bib=hidenameonly}{\@publisthideonlytrue}

\newcommand{\firstname}[1]{\def\@firstname{#1}}
\newcommand{\vonname}[1]{\def\@vonname{#1}}
\newcommand{\lastname}[1]{\def\@lastname{#1}}

\@publisthideonlytrue

\if@publistnormal
    \RequirePackage[%
            backend=biber,
            %bibstyle=publist,
            style=authoryear,
            hyperref=auto
        ]{biblatex}
    \AtEveryBibitem{\makebox[\bibhang][l]{\softbullet}}
\else
    \RequirePackage[%
            backend=biber,
            bibstyle=publist,
            labeldateparts=false,
            hyperref=auto
        ]{biblatex}
    \defbibenvironment{bibliography}
      {\list
         {\labelitemfont\softbullet}
         {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
          \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
          \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
          \def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}}}%
      {\endlist}
      {\item}
    \if@displayvon
        \plauthorname[\@firstname][\@vonname]{\@lastname}
    \else
        \plauthorname[\@firstname]{\@lastname}
    \fi
    \if@publisthideonly
        \ExecutePublistOptions{hlyear=false}
    \else\fi
    \if@publisthighlight
        \ExecutePublistOptions{plauthorhandling=highlight}
    \else\fi
\fi
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{sample.bib}
@book{dirac,
    title = {The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
    author = {Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
    isbn = {9780198520115},
    series = {International series of monographs on physics},
    year = {1981},
    publisher = {Clarendon Press},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{sample.bib}


\firstname{Paul Adrien Maurice}
\lastname{Dirac}

\begin{document}
Hello

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This is the currently best I can do with the if cases (that works):

**Edit:** seems like putting `\defbibenvironment ..` at the end of the publistnormal ifcase: `\if@publistnormal ... \else ... \defbibenvironment \fi` did not work. So this is what I have:

```
\if@publistnormal
    \RequirePackage[%
            backend=biber,
            %bibstyle=publist,
            style=authoryear,
            hyperref=auto
        ]{biblatex}
    \AtEveryBibitem{\makebox[\bibhang][l]{\softbullet}}
\else
    \if@publisthideonly
        \RequirePackage[%
                hlyear=false, % 
                backend=biber,
                bibstyle=publist,
                labeldateparts=false,
                hyperref=auto
            ]{biblatex}
        \defbibenvironment{bibliography}
          {\list
             {\labelitemfont\softbullet}
             {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
              \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
              \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
              \def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}}}%
          {\endlist}
          {\item}
    \else
        \if@publisthighlight
            \RequirePackage[%
                    plauthorhandling=highlight, % 
                    backend=biber,
                    bibstyle=publist,
                    labeldateparts=false,
                    hyperref=auto
                ]{biblatex}
            \defbibenvironment{bibliography}
              {\list
                 {\labelitemfont\softbullet}
                 {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
                  \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
                  \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
                  \def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}}}%
              {\endlist}
              {\item}
        \else
            \RequirePackage[%
                    backend=biber,
                    bibstyle=publist,
                    labeldateparts=false,
                    hyperref=auto
                ]{biblatex}
            \defbibenvironment{bibliography}
              {\list
                 {\labelitemfont\softbullet}
                 {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
                  \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
                  \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
                  \def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}}}%
              {\endlist}
              {\item}
        \fi
    \if@displayvon
        \plauthorname[\@firstname][\@vonname]{\@lastname}
    \else
        \plauthorname[\@firstname]{\@lastname}
    \fi
    \fi
\fi
```

It *feels* like there should be some simpler way to do this. Maybe it is possible to pass the optional directly to `biblatex` in `\DeclareOption` somehow?

It may very well also be that there is no better way to do it, in which case I'll accept it and just use what I have.

To clairify: all `\if@publisthighlight` is doing is including `hlyear=false` when importing biblatex, and `\if@publisthideonly` includes `plauthorhandling=highlight`.

Comment: as mentioned last time, don't do `\let\if@publisthideonly\iftrue` do `\@publisthideonlytrue`

Comment: you can use `\PassOptionsToPackage` to pass options to a package loaded later. And you don't have to use `backend=biber` and `hyperref=auto` all the time. These are the defaults anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`\ExecutePublistOptions` does work in the preamble, but only after `publist` has been loaded (as the command is defined there).

So something like this (untested) should actually work:

```tex
    \if@publistnormal
        \RequirePackage[%
                backend=biber,
                %bibstyle=publist,
                style=authoryear,
                hyperref=auto
            ]{biblatex}
        \AtEveryBibitem{\makebox[\bibhang][l]{\softbullet}}
    \else
       \RequirePackage[%
                    backend=biber,
                    style=publist,
                    labeldateparts=false,
                    hyperref=auto
                ]{biblatex}
    \fi
    \if@publisthideonly
        \ExecutePublistOptions{hlyear=false}
         \defbibenvironment{bibliography}
              {\list
                 {\labelitemfont\softbullet}
                 {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
                  \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
                  \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
                  \def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}}}%
              {\endlist}
              {\item}
      \else
          \if@publisthighlight
               \ExecutePublistOptions{plauthorhandling=highlight}
                \defbibenvironment{bibliography}
                  {\list
                     {\labelitemfont\softbullet}
                     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
                      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
                      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
                      \def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}}}%
                  {\endlist}
                  {\item}
            \else
                \defbibenvironment{bibliography}
                  {\list
                     {\labelitemfont\softbullet}
                     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
                      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
                      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}%
                      \def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}}}%
                  {\endlist}
                  {\item}
            \fi
        \if@displayvon
            \plauthorname[\@firstname][\@vonname]{\@lastname}
        \else
            \plauthorname[\@firstname]{\@lastname}
        \fi
        \fi
    \fi
```